# Swift decode JSON with unknown keys

Tags: json, swift, codable, decodable

I have a JSON file in my app bundle that looks like this

```
{
    "1": "cat",
    "2": "dog",
    "3": "elephant"
}
```

What I'd like is to be able to find the value for the "2" key for example ("dog").

I'm using [this extension](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-decode-json-from-your-app-bundle-the-easy-way) to decode the json file:

```
let config = Bundle.main.decode(Config.self, from: "config.json")
```

And I have this struct defined:

```
struct Config: Codable {
    let id: String
    let animal: String
}
```

But how do I find the animal name for the "2" key?

Comment: What about decoding as `[String: String]`?

Comment: Did you check these? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+json+unknown+keys

Comment: The `Config` struct does not reflect the example JSON you posted. You example is a simple `[String : String`].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be trying to decode your JSON as if it were an array of your `Config` structs - that would look like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "animal": "cat"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "animal": "dog"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "animal": "elephant"
  }
]
```

But your data (config.json) isn't that, it's just a JSON dictionary of String keys with String values.

You can instead "decode" it as just a String: String dictionary like:

```
let dict = Bundle.main.decode([String: String].self, from: "config.json")
```

and then `dict["2"]` would indeed be an optional string, with a value of `.some("dog")`

Or perhaps you mean your JSON to be an *array* of `Config`'s, if you change the contents of config.json file to the above, and then decode it with:

```
let config = Bundle.main.decode([Config].self, from: "config.json")
```

Then the animal with id of 2 would be, e.g.

```
config.first(where: { $0.id == "2" })?.animal
```